# Responsive div class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my website responsive and I have already set the divs' min-height and set the `display: inline-block`. I already did it to one of the div but then when I tried to make it on the others, it just maintained its min-height. I can see the words adjust when I tried it out but the size/height of the div stayed the same. I think it's because the positions of the divs are in absolute but I also tried to set it to relative, but then the design messed up.

```css
.fullbanner2 {
  width: 95.2%;
  min-height: 90vh;
}


.banner2left, .banner2right {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.banner2left {
  width: 52%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}


.banner2left h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Athena', sans-serif;
}


.banner2left p {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -2%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  color: #666695;
}


.banner2right {
  background: url(../colors-n-pics/picture2.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  margin-left: 52%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 43.2%;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullbanner2">
    <div class="banner2left">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> 
      <p>Curabitur congue non diam id venenatis. Ut eget dolor dictum, iaculis lacus quis, commodo justo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner2right">
    </div>
  </div>
   
  <div class="statement1">
  <h2><center>Curabitur dolor erat, accumsan in elit vitae. Curabitur dolor erat, accumsan in elit vitae, finibus malesuada erat. Ut nibh enim, mollis vitae diam non, placerat fringilla nulla. Proin elementum, lectus sed mollis convallis. </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<center>` tag has been obsolete for many years. Do not use it.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not really part of responsive design. Read up on the fundamentals: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive Also...why reinvent the wheel? You can make it a lot easier on yourself if you get to grips with the grid system in something like materialize or bootstrap, and then look at freestyling. Just a thought. In essence, for a % based layout system you'll need to incorporate media queries to shift your columns from 100% on mobile to 50% on tablet/desktop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @poyo instead of center tags, you can use text-align:center; to center text